# SQL: Updating from list with subquery versus FROM

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm curious about the performance difference between the two examples, and whether they are truly equivalent within postgreSQL. It seems like the only place where performance could diverge would be when I assign using lists rather than using FROM.

These examples are based on the [PostgreSQL Exercises](https://pgexercises.com) website, for the [Update Calculated prompt](https://pgexercises.com/questions/updates/updatecalculated.html)

Example using lists:

```
update cd.facilities
    set (membercost, guestcost) = (select membercost1.1, guestcost1.1 from cd.facilities where facid = 0)
    where facid = 1
```

Example with FROM:

```
update cd.facilities fac
    set
        membercost = fac2.membercost1.1,
        guestcost = fac2.guestcost1.1
    from (select * from cd.facilities where facid = 0) fac2
    where fac.facid = 1
```

Comment: Use **explain** statement to see how Postgres Query plan Builder works, **analyze** can be added to get more information. Further, check if **partitioning** can be carried out on the table, and of course the creation of **indexes.**

Answer (score 0):

You should actually try the queries.  I would expect the performance to be similar.  Both would use indexes if available, for instance.

You can write this without subqueries, though:

```
update cd.facilities f1
    set membercost = f0.membercost1.1,
        guestcost = f0.guestcost1.1
    from  cd.facilities f0
    where fo.facid = 0 and
          f1.facid = 1;
```

For all of these, I would recommend an index on `facilities(facid)`.  You probably have this already if `facid` is a primary key.